How to configure development build and DevTools for vue 3 on vite
I recently migrated an existing Vue 3 project from Vue CLI to Vite.
There's an issue with the app that's specific to a situation happening in production and there's no error in Chrome DevTools console so I thought maybe I could insepct the components using Vue DevTools, which is something I have done many times in other projects. But this time, I couldn't. The so called development build is exactly the same as production build.
this is my package.json:
{
  "name": "tour-app",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "buildDev": "vite --mode development build"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist/*.js"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "5.9.55",
    "@vuelidate/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.44",
    "@vuelidate/validators": "^2.0.0-alpha.31",
    "@vueuse/core": "^9.6.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "pinia": "^2.0.16",
    "pinia-plugin-persistedstate": "^2.1.1",
    "roboto-fontface": "*",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-axios": "^3.4.1",
    "vue-recaptcha-v3": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.13",
    "vue-types": "^5.0.2",
    "webfontloader": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/webfontloader": "^1.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^10",
    "eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "json-server": "^0.17.0",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3",
    "vite": "^5.2.11",
    "vite-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.3",
    "vuetify": "^3.6.7"
  }
}

As you can see I've add a buildDev script that runs vite build in development mode. When run it outputs the following:
> tour-app@0.2.0 build
> vite build --mode development

vite v5.2.11 building for development...
✓ 409 modules transformed.
dist/index.html                                                            0.89 kB │ gzip:   0.48 kB
dist/.vite/manifest.json                                                   1.44 kB │ gzip:   0.26 kB
dist/booking/assets/PAP.TourBooking.materialdesignicons-webfont.woff2    325.24 kB
dist/booking/assets/PAP.TourBooking.materialdesignicons-webfont.woff     465.19 kB
dist/booking/assets/PAP.TourBooking.materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf    1,026.18 kB
dist/booking/assets/PAP.TourBooking.materialdesignicons-webfont.eot    1,026.40 kB
dist/booking/assets/PAP.TourBooking.index.css                            965.51 kB │ gzip: 134.87 kB
dist/booking/assets/PAP.TourBooking.index.js                             593.62 kB │ gzip: 195.71 kB

(!) Some chunks are larger than 500 kB after minification. Consider:
- Using dynamic import() to code-split the application
- Use build.rollupOptions.output.manualChunks to improve chunking: https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-manualchunks
- Adjust chunk size limit for this warning via build.chunkSizeWarningLimit.
✓ built in 3.30s

As printed in the message above, vite says its building for development, so mode is correctly passed to vite, but it doesn't result in building the project in a different manner as building for production.
I must've done the migration wrong somehow. for the reference here's my vite.config.js:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import vuetify from 'vite-plugin-vuetify';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import path from 'path';

const filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const pathSegments = path.dirname(filename);

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(),
  vuetify({
    autoImport: { labs: true }
  })],
  //   server:{
  //     proxy:{
  //       '/api': 'http://localhost:55032',
  //     }
  //   },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(pathSegments, './src'),
      vue: "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js",
      mainFields: [
        'browser',
        'module',
        'main',
        'jsnext:main',
        'jsnext'
      ]
    },
    extensions: ['.mjs', '.js', '.ts', '.json'],
  },
  build: {
    minify: true,
    manifest: true,
    outDir: "dist",
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {

        entryFileNames: "booking/assets/PAP.TourBooking.[name].js",
        assetFileNames: "booking/assets/PAP.TourBooking.[name][extname]",
      }
    },
  }
})

I also thought maybe I could stick to the production build and just force activate DevTools in production, but no matter how much I searched and read the documents I could't find how to do it in vite, so I resorted to posting my question on stackoverflow.
note that this project uses tailwind+postcss alongisde with vuetify

See https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/vue-force-dev/oohfffedbkbjnbpbbedapppafmlnccmb

@EstusFlask Thanks a lot! This actually helped me do the debugging without going through the problem of fixing the development build. But still, I'm determined to solve the dev build issue or at least become convinced that I should forget about it

Glad it helped. It's unclear how you expect dev mode to differ. Is it the availability of vue devtools that matters? You have build.minify set for all builds unconditionally at least. Check what MODE, PROD and DEV vars are https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode in dev mode. This can be affected with .env files if there are any.

@EstusFlask You're right.  I've already overridden the default behavior with a statically set configuration, and there's no mode-specific env file. So I was having invalid expections.
